# autocomplete attribute support

Tags: html, autocomplete

I want to use the `autocomplete` attribute on a form on a webpage. Specifically, `autocomplete="tel-local"` and such (i.e. autocompletes that specify what goes in a field)

I'd like to know how widely supported it is, and, if possible, what browsers support it. My attempts to google it have failed...

Also, as far as I can think, even in browsers that fail to support it, using the attribute should not cause problems. Is there any problem that I can cause by using it?

---

The spec that I intend to use is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill (which, as far as I know, is the current spec).

Comment: No, an attribute not supported by a browser is simply ignored. A quick google search learned me that IE (5+), FireFox and Chrome all support it.

Comment: Also notice, that adding this attribute only makes sense on `type="text'` or `type="tel"` inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The `autocomplete` attribute as such is well supported, see [MDN info on `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). However, this only applies to its original design, formally [described](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute) in the W3C HTML5 Recommendation. Various drafts contained lists of other values, but they were dropped from the Rec due to lack of implementations. Such ideas are retained in the [HTML 5.1 draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute) (work in progress) and in what the WHATWG group calls “Living HTML Standard” (a mutable document that expresses a person’s view of what is “standard HTML” today).

Support to values other than `on` and `off` in browsers is obscure. The current version of Firefox surely lacks support, since other values aren’t even reflected in the DOM, i.e. the `autocomplete` property of an element node cannot have other values (so e.g. `autocomplete=tel-local` is ignored, which normally means defaulting to `autocomplete=on`). Chrome and IE let you set the attribute to any value, in the sense of setting the property, but its effect appears to be undocumented. In Chrome, `autocomplete=tel-local` seems to have *some* effect, but to me it suggests just some text strings as values (perhaps due to some tests I have made previously).

The problem in support is that it *may* exist. It is then somewhat unpredictable *how* a browser implements the attribute.